# Element inspector icon or shortcut in Chrome menu bar

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

Would there be menu icon (or any other shortcut) available for Chrome that allows you to inspect the page HTML and CSS? Firebug provides this inspector element icon in Firefox' main toolbar and I'm using it quite a lot.

[image]

Currently the only way to toggle the element inspector glass is by toggling the whole development toolset, and then clicking the inspector, or by right-mouse clicking an element in the page, which is to my opinion far from accurate.

An menu icon (or shortcut - I'm on Mac) that shortcuts the inspector glass would save me a lot of time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Cmd + Shift + C</kbd> lets you use the element inspector directly, and opens DevTools if it's not open already.

Comment: I replaced the *shift* with *alt* in your answer. *Cmd + Alt + C* does the job here. Thank you for pushing me in the right direction! (Wasn't me that gave your reply a minus btw - leveled it with a +1)

Comment: Happy to help. Both Alt and Shift are working for me.

Answer (score 0):

The edit was rejected for some reason. <kbd>Cmd + Alt + C</kbd> seems to do the job for me. Thanks for pushing me in the right direction, Matt.